# I want to Itrate JSON and convert into rows from postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql, loops, for-loop

Basically I want to itrate JSON till its length from table but rest of values of remains same till current JSON ends.
My Table format is like this

| id | line | txndate | metadata | docnumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 363 | [{"Id": "0", "Amount": 135000.0, "DetailType": "JournalEntryLineDetail", "Description": "Paid Office Rent Of Office", "JournalEntryLineDetail": {"AccountRef": {"name": "Rent or lease payments", "value": "57"}, "PostingType": "Debit"}}, {"Id": "1", "Amount": 135000.0, "DetailType": "JournalEntryLineDetail", "Description": "Paid Office Rent Of Office", "JournalEntryLineDetail": {"AccountRef": {"name": "Cash and cash equivalents:Bank", "value": "83"}, "PostingType": "Credit"}}] | 2021-08-16 00:00:00.000000 +00:00 | {"CreateTime": "2021-08-20T05:39:38.000000Z", "LastUpdatedTime": "2021-08-20T05:39:38.000000Z"} | 332 |
| 610 | [{"Id": "0", "Amount": 4138088.25, "DetailType": "JournalEntryLineDetail", "Description": "Deposit in Bank", "JournalEntryLineDetail": {"AccountRef": {"name": "Cash and cash equivalents:Bank", "value": "83"}, "PostingType": "Debit"}}, {"Id": "1", "Amount": 4138088.25, "DetailType": "JournalEntryLineDetail", "Description": "Deposit in Bank", "JournalEntryLineDetail": {"AccountRef": {"name": "Share capital", "value": "8"}, "PostingType": "Credit"}}, {"Id": "2", "DetailType": "DescriptionOnly", "Description": "Deposit in Bank"}] | 2021-10-11 00:00:00.000000 +00:00 | {"CreateTime": "2021-10-13T10:44:09.000000Z", "LastUpdatedTime": "2021-10-13T10:44:09.000000Z"} | 560 |
| 381 | [{"Id": "0", "Amount": 30000.0, "DetailType": "JournalEntryLineDetail", "Description": "Paid to Punkish", "JournalEntryLineDetail": {"AccountRef": {"name": "Advance Against Salary", "value": "103"}, "PostingType": "Debit"}}, {"Id": "1", "Amount": 30000.0, "DetailType": "JournalEntryLineDetail", "Description": "Paid to Punkish", "JournalEntryLineDetail": {"AccountRef": {"name": "Cash and cash equivalents:Bank", "value": "83"}, "PostingType": "Credit"}}] | 2021-07-01 00:00:00.000000 +00:00 | {"CreateTime": "2021-08-23T05:31:42.000000Z", "LastUpdatedTime": "2021-08-23T05:47:03.000000Z"} | 521 |

But I want to extract information like following table

| id | line_id | Amount | Description | name | value | posting_type | txndate | CreatedTime | LastUpdatedTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 363 | 0 | 13500 | Paid Office Rent Of Office | Rent or lease payments | 57 | Debit | 2021-08-16 00:00:00.000000 +00:00 | 2021-08-20T05:39:38.000000Z | 2021-08-20T05:39:38.000000Z |
| 363 | 1 | 13500 | Paid Office Rent Of Office | Cash and cash equivalents:Bank | 83 | Cebit | 2021-08-16 00:00:00.000000 +00:00 | 2021-08-20T05:39:38.000000Z | 2021-08-20T05:39:38.000000Z |
| 610 | 0 | 4138088.25 | Deposit in Bank | Cash and cash equivalents:Bank | 83 | Debit | 2021-10-11 00:00:00.000000 +00:00 | 2021-10-13T10:44:09.000000Z | 2021-10-13T10:44:09.000000Z |
| 610 | 1 | 4138088.25 | .......... | .. | ... | ... | 2021-10-11 00:00:00.000000 +00:00 | 2021-10-13T10:44:09.000000Z | 2021-10-13T10:44:09.000000Z |
| 610 | 2 | 4138088.25 | .......... | .. | ... | ... | 2021-10-11 00:00:00.000000 +00:00 | 2021-10-13T10:44:09.000000Z | 2021-10-13T10:44:09.000000Z |
| 610 | 3 | 4138088.25 | .......... | .. | ... | ... | 2021-10-11 00:00:00.000000 +00:00 | 2021-10-13T10:44:09.000000Z | 2021-10-13T10:44:09.000000Z |

I want to convert JSON column enteries into rows but want preserve id, txndate, CreatedTime, and LastUpdatedTime same till the length of JSON column which is *line* in my case.

Please guide me with solution if possible.
Note: I am using Postgresql and datatype of `line` column is jsonb

Comment: Which database do you use? MySQL or Postgres?

Comment: @Pooya I am using Postgresql

Comment: What is a type of `line` column? JSON or JSONB?

Comment: @Pooya the type of `line` column is jsonb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, You can use `jsonb_array_elements` function to convert an array of JSON to row and then query on each row

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=38774d529324e2ea0a6edfc50f3d6531)

```sql
select
  t.id,
  e.value ->> 'Id' as line_id,
  e.value ->> 'Amount' as amount,
  e.value ->> 'Description' as description,
  e.value -> 'JournalEntryLineDetail' -> 'AccountRef' ->> 'name' as name,
  e.value -> 'JournalEntryLineDetail' -> 'AccountRef' ->> 'value' as value,
  e.value -> 'JournalEntryLineDetail' ->> 'PostingType' as posting_type,
  t.txndate,
  t.metadata ->> 'CreateTime' as CreatedTime,
  t.metadata ->> 'LastUpdatedTime' as LastUpdatedTime
from
  test t
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(t.line) e
```